# How to join the tables KNBK and TIBAN?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, opensql

I am trying to read the table `TIBAN` only in the cases when the field `BANKN` of the `KNBK` table contains the string "IBAN". The problem that I am having is reading the table `TIBAN`. For the `KNBK` table I used the key `kunnr` to search the table, but the table `TIBAN` does not contain this field. The code is as follows:

```
 LOOP AT lt_data_bsec ASSIGNING <ls_data_bsec>.

      READ TABLE lt_data_knbk ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_data_knbk>) 
            WITH KEY kunnr = <ls_data_bsec>-kunnr BINARY SEARCH .

      IF <ls_data_knbk>-bankn_kn CS '<IBAN>'.

      >>>>> READ TABLE lt_data_tiban ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_data_tiban>).

        IF <ls_data_bsec> IS ASSIGNED 
              AND <ls_data_tiban> IS ASSIGNED
              AND ( <ls_data_bsec>-banks_bs NE <ls_data_tiban>-banks_kn
                 OR <ls_data_bsec>-bankl_bs NE <ls_data_tiban>-bankl_kn
                 OR <ls_data_bsec>-bankn_bs NE <ls_data_tiban>-bankn_kn ).

        ENDIF.
```

The declaration of the `lt_data_knbk` table is:

```
SELECT kunnr,
           banks AS banks_kn,
           bankl AS bankl_kn,
           bankn AS bankn_kn
      FROM knbk
      INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_data_knbk)
      FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @lt_data_bsec
      WHERE kunnr = @lt_data_bsec-kunnr
      ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY.
```

And the declaration of the `lt_data_tiban` is:

```
SELECT banks AS banks_tb,
           bankl AS bankl_tb,
           bankn AS bankn_tb
      FROM tiban
      INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_data_tiban).
```

Also the declaration of the `lt_data_bsec` is of the type `gty_out`:

```
BEGIN OF gty_out,
         bukrs    TYPE bukrs,
         belnr    TYPE belnr_d,
         buzei    TYPE buzei,
         budat    TYPE budat,
         kunnr    TYPE kunnr,
         banks_kn TYPE banks,
         bankl_kn TYPE bankk,
         bankn_kn TYPE bankn,
         banks_bs TYPE banks,
         bankl_bs TYPE bankk,
         bankn_bs TYPE bankn,
         banks_tb TYPE banks,
         bankl_tb TYPE bankk,
         bankn_tb TYPE bankn,
       END OF gty_out,
```

I am having an error in the line that I have marked in the code as it needs a key field to do the reading of the table.

May anyone know what type of field do I need to do a search of the `TIBAN` table, just like I did for the `KNBK` table?

Comment: The field KNBK-BANKN is the bank account number of the customer, it should _never_ contain the string 'IBAN'. There is a customer (table KNA1), the customer has a bank account (table KNBK), the bank account has an IBAN (table TIBAN). However the TIBAN entry does not exist by default, it has to be generated separately. On the other hand you talk about table BSEC. Table BSEC contains the -so called- one time customers, these customers don't have a customer number (KUNNR) in the system, therefore also don't have corresponding KNA1 / KNBK entries.

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai That is incorrect.  I have several systems here with entries in KNBK where the field BANKN has a value of `<IBAN>nnnnnnnnnnnn`. It means that the bank account of that customer is a SEPA account and that its IBAN number can be found in table TIBAN.

Comment: @Philipp that is utterly strange. The field BANKN is 18 characters long, and for Hungary the bank account number is 16 charcters long, which means it is not possible to add a 6 character long prefix (i. e. <IBAN>) for this country. On the other hand, it does not really matter, whether the IBAN exists or not in the table IBAN. It can always be generated with the respective FM

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai this is not strange at all. That's how FI handles the new IBAN numbers via the old bank tables. Note that `nnnnnnnnnnnn` is not a valid legacy account number *or* IBAN number. It's an auto-incrementing number which is used as an index for table TIBAN.

Comment: @Phillip is it S/4?

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai No, that's the case since we introduced SEPA a couple years ago. Not sure if that happens before or after IBAN-only, though.

Comment: @Philipp OK thanks. I did some research, this is the IBAN only approach, but it belongs to MDG (not classical FI). It seems like I have completely missed it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to acquire your bank data by doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with TIBAN.

```
SELECT knbk~kunnr AS kunnr,
       knbk~banks AS banks_kn,
       knbk~bankl AS bankl_kn,
       knbk~bankn AS bankn_kn,
       knbk~bkont AS bkont_kn,
       tiban~iban AS iban
  FROM knbk
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tiban ON
       tiban~banks = knbk~banks AND
       tiban~bankl = knbk~bankl AND
       tiban~bankn = knbk~bankn AND
       tiban~bkont = knbk~bkont
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_data_knbk)
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @lt_data_bsec
  WHERE knbk~kunnr = @lt_data_bsec-kunnr
  ORDER BY knbk~banks knbk~bankl knbk~bankn knbk~bkont.
```

The result will be a table with all entries from `KNBK`, plus a field `IBAN` which will be filled from `TIBAN` if a corresponding row exists and be initial when no corresponding row exists.

Now you can just determine whether or not you have an IBAN like this:

```
LOOP AT lt_data_knbk ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_data_knbk>).
   IF <ls_data_knbk>-iban IS INITIAL.
       " classic bank number + account number account
   ELSE.
       " IBAN account     
   ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your task is a perfect case where [ABAP CDS associations](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/10/30/part8.-cds-views-joins-and-associations/) aka [Lazy Join](https://sapyard.com/cds-part-15-associations-in-cds-views-i/) come into play.

If you are on the recent version of ABAP and is able to create CDS, nothing prevents you from creating this

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: ‘ZCUST_TIBAN_SQL’
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
@EndUserText.label: ‘TIBAN’
 
define view ZCUST_TIBAN as select from knbk as cus
association [0..1] to tiban as _an 
                 on  cus.kunnr = _an.kunnr
                 and cus.banks = _an.banks
                 and cus.bankl = _an.bankl
                 and cus.bankn = _an.bankn
                 and cus.bkont = _an.bkont
{
       cus.kunnr,
       cus.banks AS banks_kn,
       cus.bankl AS bankl_kn,
       cus.bankn AS bankn_kn,
       cus.bkont AS bkont_kn,
       _iban~
} WHERE cus.bankn like '%IBAN%'
```

Then you can use this association in all your further requirements:

```
SELECT  banks_kn, bankl_kn, bankn_kn, bkont_kn
       \_iban-iban          AS IBAN,
       \_iban-valid_from    AS IBAN_validity
  FROM zcust_tiban
 WHERE kunnr IN @lr_customers
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_data_knbk).

...
READ TABLE lt_data_knbk ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_data_knbk>) 
        WITH KEY kunnr = <ls_data_bsec>-kunnr BINARY SEARCH.
...
```

Key points to pay attention to:

- an association with 0..1 cardinality like above does not do actual JOIN until the fields from the associated table `TIBAN` are requested like in the above SELECT. This can be more performant and more universal than `LEFT OUTER JOIN` approach suggested by Philipp.
- it is reusable and can be used in further selects/associations as a source